# Why maven cachea all versions of my dependency on local?

Tags: maven

I have Testng version 7.0.0 dependency in my pom file and why does it caches all versions of Testng on my local .m2 folder?
How can I avoid that to save time?

Comment: First you can't avoid that. And why would it save time?

Comment: It only cashes those versions that are requested during the build. Depending on the dependency tree, this may be more than one.